# How to get the SID of the current machine?

Tags: winapi

I know how to get the SID for the current **user**. Conceptually the answer is:

- Use **OpenThreadToken** (or **OpenProcessToken**) to get the security `TOKEN` of the running user
- use **GetTokenInformation** to get the **TOKEN_USER** structure
- and then `TOKEN_USER.Sid` is the Sid

So in pseudocode:

```
String GetCurrentUserSid()
{
   // Get the calling thread's access token.
   TOKEN hToken;
   if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, true, out hToken)
   { 
       if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
          RaiseLastWin32Error();

       // No thread token exists, try again against the process token
       if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, out hToken)
          RaiseLastWin32Error();
   }
   try
   {
      // Obtain the size of the user information in the token.
      DWORD cbReturned;
      GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, nil, 0, out cbReturned);

      //Allocate memory and try again for real
      TOKEN_USER* tiUser = GetMemory(cbReturned);
      if (!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, tiUser, cbReturned, out cbReturned))
      RaiseLastWin32Error();
   }
   finally
   {
      CloseHandle(hToken);
   }

   //Convert the structure to a string
   return SidToString(tiUser.User.Sid);
}
```

### But how to do it for the current machine?

```
String GetCurrentMachineSid()
{
   // TODO: Ask Stackoverflow
}
```

## Bonus Reading

- [The Machine SID Duplication Myth (and Why Sysprep Matters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/11/03/the-machine-sid-duplication-myth-and-why-sysprep-matters/)
- [Machine SIDs and Domain SIDs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2009/11/05/machine-sids-and-domain-sids/)
- [How to find SID of computer](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1974956-how-to-find-sid-of-computer)

Comment: but how *Sysinternals PsGetSid tool* get it - ok for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [*You can see the machine SID on your computer by running Sysinternals
>   PsGetSid with no parameters*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2009/11/05/machine-sids-and-domain-sids/)

so i simply look under debugger how *PsGetSid* do this.

it get *SID* from [`POLICY_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lsalookup/ns-lsalookup-_policy_account_domain_info) - *DomainSid : Pointer to the SID of the account domain*

code can be next

```
LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle;

LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes = { sizeof(ObjectAttributes) };

NTSTATUS status = LsaOpenPolicy(0, &ObjectAttributes, POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &PolicyHandle);

if (0 <= status)
{
    POLICY_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN_INFO* ppadi;

    status = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle, PolicyAccountDomainInformation, (void**)&ppadi);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PWSTR szSid;
        BOOL b = ConvertSidToStringSidW(ppadi->DomainSid, &szSid);
        LsaFreeMemory(ppadi);

        if (b)
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szSid);
            LocalFree(szSid);
        }
    }

    LsaClose(PolicyHandle);
}
```